# Issue in posting hiddeninput in yii2

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I am trying to post a hidden value with yii2 active form, but it's not defined in my database table. Which is why the active record model from that table produces a `"Getting unknown property"` error.

Is there any way to post a value with active form without making its field in database table or defining it in the active record model to just post the value with the form?

This is my form:

```
<?php

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['twit/update-reply'],
]);
?>
<?= $form->field($model,'twit')->textarea(['value' => $twit]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'id')->hiddeninput(['value' => $id]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'rid')->hiddeninput(['value' => $rid]); ?>

<?= Html::SubmitButton('بروز رسانی',['class' => 'btn btn-success green']); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The `$form->field($model,'rid')` input in this form is not defined in model and causes the above mentioned error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: define in your model public $rid;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ActiveForm`, you can add `Model` property only as a field. For solve the problem, you have two solution:

- Define a property on your model,
- Post your hidden input without `ActiveForm` field, i.e. replace

  ```
  <?= $form->field($model,'id')->hiddeninput(['value' => $id]); ?>
  ```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>" />
```

`ActiveForm` as is in its name, show behavior of model actively, for example if you define a rule on your model for attribute called `userEmail` that must be an email, `ActiveForm` check your rule that `userEmail` be have a pattern like `emailName@emailHost.emailDomain` (More precisely `([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)@([A-Za-z0-9]+).([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]{2,3})` for example), then if your model, be an instance of a record on your table, `ActiveForm` populate your field on your HTML form with saved value.